# SQL "Where" vs Knuth-Moriss-Prat

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have a table(A) which contains texts(there is no any text length limitation and text counts can be more than 2000) and another table(B), which contains maximum 2000 static words.
I need to find occurrences of words from table B in texts of table A. And now, I am thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. Store the words of table A in array and apply [Knuth-Moriss-Prat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to find occurrences.
2. Store the words of table A in array and use SQL "WHERE" condition to find occurrences.

Which method would you suggest for such kind of problem?

Comment: What does "find occurances" mean?  Do you just need to know if any B words are in each A string, or which ones, or how many, or where they are?

Comment: find occurrences means that the text contains the word.

Answer (score 1):

Store the b words in a hash table, then look up each A word in it.

Comment: how can I check whether the hash of b words(text) contains the specific word?